# Removing options from select and re-appending changes selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just realized a strange behaviour when removing and re-appending options to a select element. It happens that if one of the options is selected, after appended, the next item becomes selected instead of the original one. Consider the following html:

```js
var $opts = $("#sel option").remove();
console.log($opts);
$("#sel").append($opts);
```

```html
<select id="sel">
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option selected="selected">C</option>
    <option>D</option>
</select>
(Look in the console.)
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

*(Or as a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6q9h50oh/))*

It makes the option with value `"D"` to be selected and not the option with value `"C"`, as defined originally. Notice the options printed in the console, the attribute `selected` is changed after the `remove()` method.

Why does that happen?

**Note:** I know how to *fix* it or work around it, that's not the question. The question is why does it happen?

Comment: In general its actually selecting the `next` option of last `selected` option. Now if you keep the last option as selected, the same will remain since there is no next option present after the `selected` one. This is what I noticed which is strange for me too.. :)

Comment: @GuruprasadRao sure. I realized it happens the same with `detach()` too.

Comment: @TJCrowder But the `detach` should hold all the properties relating to the elements right?

Comment: I think that when you call `remove` it iterates over the results returned by your jquery selector (i.e.: the options) and removes them one at a time, likely in order from first to last.  when you remove the `selected` 3rd option, the last remaining option 'D' would be the selected, since its the only option left.

Comment: @GlennFerrie: That's definitely part of it, although the reality is much more interesting when you delve into it and varies not only by browser (IE11, Firefox, and Chrome all do different things), but also depending on how aggressively you *observe* the process (Chrome changes its behavior if you're watching). I've gone into a fair bit of detail in my (updated) answer.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao: My earlier comment replying to you (now deleted) turns out to have been a simplification that may well have been correct on Firefox, but isn't on IE11 or Chrome. I've updated my answer below with details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fascinating question.

I believe it's down to the browser automatically selecting an option when the only selected option is removed, and then what happens when you add an option into a box that has the `selected` flag set. It also appears to be browser-specific, which probably shouldn't surprise us. But even more, Chrome *varies* its behavior depending on how closely we're watching. That *did* surprise me. Details below.

First, let's use something like your updated example, but where the one that we start out with selected is neither first nor last, and see where we end up. So we'll have A, B, C, D, and E, and start out with B selected:

```js
$("input[type=button]").on("click", function() {
  var $opts = $("#sel option").remove();
  $("#sel").append($opts);
});
```

```html
<select id="sel">
    <option>A</option>
    <option selected="selected">B</option>
    <option>C</option>
    <option>D</option>
    <option>E</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Go">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The results we observe vary by browser:

- Chrome ends up on C, the one *after* the one that was selected at the outset (not the last one).
- IE11 ends up on B, which is to say, it doesn't *seem* to change the selected flags as we remove/add.
- Firefox ends up on E (the last one).

To make matters worse, Chrome's behavior *varies* depending on whether we observe the `selected` property of the elements as this is happening or not. Heisenbug! If we observe it, it ends up doing what Firefox does (E) instead of C.

That gives us a big clue as to what's happening in Chrome. But let's start with the easy ones:

#### IE11

It would appear that IE11 just leaves the flags alone, probably because it doesn't worry about updating them while the JavaScript code is running, only when it yields back and IE updates its UI.

#### Firefox

Firefox makes sense if it's proactive about setting the `selected` flag on an option when there are none selected in the box (because we removed the selected one):

1. We remove A, B remains selected.
2. We remove B, C becomes selected because B isn't in the box anymore and the box needs to have at least one selected option. The removed option's flag remains set, which is important in a minute
3. Step 2 repeats when we remove C and D.
4. We remove E. At this point, C, D, and E all have the flag set.
5. We add A to the box. Since it's the only option the box has, it gets its `selected` flag set.
6. We add B to the box. Since B's `selected` flag is set, it becomes the selected property and A is de-selected.
7. Step 6 repeats as we add C, D, and E back.
8. We end up with E selected.

We can watch IE11 and Firefox happen, since they don't change their behavior depending on whether we observe them:

```js
var $opts = $("#sel option");
showOptions("Before", $opts);
$opts.each(function() {
  var opt = $(this);
  opt.remove();
  showOptions("After removing " + opt.text(), $opts);
});
$opts.each(function() {
  var opt = $(this);
  $("#sel").append(opt);
  showOptions("After appending " + opt.text(), $opts);
});
function showOptions(label, $opts) {
  var row = $("<tr>");
  row.append($("<td>").text(label).addClass("label"));
  $opts.each(function() {
    row.append($("<td>").text(this.selected ? "*" : "o"));
  });
  row.appendTo("#results");
}
```

```css
th, td {
  min-width: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px;
}
table, th, td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}
.label {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<select id="sel">
    <option>A</option>
    <option selected="selected">B</option>
    <option>C</option>
    <option>D</option>
    <option>E</option>
</select>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
      <th>D</th>
      <th>E</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="results">
  </tbody>
</table>
* = selected, o = not selected

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

#### Chrome

Which brings us to the hard one: Chrome. Chrome changes its behavior based on whether we observe the `selected` property as we go. Specifically, it changes its behavior if we observe `selected` on the options that are still in the select box as we remove them. It doesn't care if we look at `selected` on the removed ones, and it doesn't care whether we look at `selected` as we're appending. Just as we're removing, and just the ones we haven't removed yet.

First, here's proof:

```js
$("#btn").on("click", function() {
  var observeLTE = true;
  var observeGT = true;
  var index;
  var $opts = $("#sel option");
  showOptions("Before", $opts);
  observeLTE = $("#cbremove")[0].checked;
  observeGT = $("#cbremoveun")[0].checked;
  $opts.each(function(i) {
    var opt = $(this);
    index = i;
    opt.remove();
    showOptions("After removing " + opt.text(), $opts);
  });
  observeLTE = observeGT = $("#cbappend")[0].checked;
  $opts.each(function(i) {
    var opt = $(this);
    index = i;
    $("#sel").append(opt);
    showOptions("After appending " + opt.text(), $opts);
  });

  function showOptions(label, $opts) {
    var row = $("<tr>");
    row.append($("<td>").text(label).addClass("label"));
    $opts.each(function(i) {
      var selected;
      if ((observeLTE && i <= index) || (observeGT && i > index)) {
        selected = this.selected ? "*" : "o";
      } else {
        selected = "-";
      }
      row.append($("<td>").text(selected));
    });
    row.appendTo("#results");
  }
});
```

```css
th, td {
  min-width: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px;
}
table, th, td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}
.label {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>
    <input id="cbremove" type="checkbox">Observe <code>selected</code> on removed options while removing
  </label>
</div>
<div>
  <label>
    <input id="cbremoveun" type="checkbox">Observe <code>selected</code> on UNremoved options while removing
  </label>
</div>
<div>
  <label>
    <input id="cbappend" type="checkbox">Observe <code>selected</code> while appending
  </label>
</div>
<select id="sel">
  <option>A</option>
  <option selected="selected">B</option>
  <option>C</option>
  <option>D</option>
  <option>E</option>
</select>
<input id="btn" type="button" value="Go">
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
      <th>D</th>
      <th>E</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="results">
  </tbody>
</table>
* = selected, o = not selected, - = not observed

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you give that a spin (on Chrome, obviously), you'll notice that you end up on C regardless of what you do with the first or last checkbox, but checking the middle checkbox makes you end up on E.

That gives us enough data to *infer* an explanation. I can't say it actually **is** the explanation, just that it fits the available data. If someone wanted to be more thorough, they could step through Chrome's internal code in a debug build. I decided that was overkill.

So here's my answer, which I stress again is *inferred*:

1. Chrome sets the `selected` property on the `HTMLOptionElement` instance **lazily**. That is, if you don't read the property's value, Chrome doesn't check to make sure that the property reflects the current state of things.
2. It reads the `selected` property when queuing a `change` event.
3. It doesn't queue a `change` event if one is already pending for that select box.

Based on that, here's what I think happens in Chrome:

1. We remove A, B remains selected. No `change` event because the value hasn't changed.
2. We remove B, C becomes selected because B isn't in the box anymore and the box needs to have at least one selected option. This queues a `change` event, which observes `selected` and thus sets the property on C.
3. We remove C. D becomes selected (in some sense), but because there's a `change` event pending, no new `change` event is queued, and so D's `selected` isn't observed and its value isn't updated; it remains `false` even though **if** we read it, it would turn `true`.
4. Same again when removing D. No change event, no observation.
5. We end up with the option elements having `selected` as `true` on B and C, but none of the others, because D and E weren't observed while they were the selected option and didn't update their value. We know those are their values because we're allowed to observe them at that point.
6. We add back the elements in order, and as with Firefox, adding an element that has `selected = true` when another element is already selected deselects the previous element. So B is deselected when C is added. C is left alone when we add D and E because their `selected` property is `false`.

***Whew***, that was fun to figure out.

Comment: But what is the sequence to remove the elements? I mean, if the `selected` is the first element, after the append, the second will be selected, not the last. http://jsfiddle.net/6q9h50oh/2/

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown: As you were asking I was adding the snippet above to demonstrate what happens., hopefully that makes it clear.

Comment: I got your point, but I'm still confused. In your code, it really does what you say, about the order of the removals. But if you use `remove()` in all options at once, the strange behaviour still occurs. I mean, if you remove and the first option is selected, then after appended, the second will be selected, and not the last. It should be, as the last would be set as selected in the remove proccess. But it doesn't happens. In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6q9h50oh/2/) you can see what i'm saying.  It will append as selected always the next option, different to your *step* removal code.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown: Heisenberg strikes again. That's fascinating. Let me see if I can work out what's happening *there*.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown: Interestingly, this "it's the next one" behavior seems to be Chrome-specific. On Firefox, even [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6q9h50oh/2/) ends up on D instead of B as in Chrome. On IE, we end up with A, not B or D. I can make Firefox's and IE's behavior make sense. I cannot immediately make sense of Chrome's behavior.

Comment: Well noted. I didn't checked in others browsers. So I think your initial explanation solves the question.

Comment: Checked the [jquery source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L206) and it does what you said, actually.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown: I think I've figured out Chrome, and why it varies based on whether you observe. I've updated the answer to explain my reasoning.

Comment: Its an insanely nice answer. I didn't know it interested so much to you. Awesome work, thank you!